# Symfony doctrine, update entity without form?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

Not sure if I have this right but I made my own custom form in the twig template with the action path going to  a controller that will update the entity. I've only ever seen update methods using form with `$form->handleRequest($request)`, then with a `$em->flush();` Since I haven't made a form through Symfony's form component, I don't know how I can access it from the template in order to flush it into the database.

Here's how I have my action controller:

```
/**
 * @param $subid
 * @param Request $request
 * @Route("/editparts/{subid}/", name="updateparts")
 * @Template("editparts.html.twig")
 * @Method("POST")
 */
public function updatePartsAction(Request $request, $subid) {
    $r = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $r->getRepository('MainBundle:MainSub')->findOneById($subid);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Parts entity to edit.');
    }

    // what is this step???

    $r->flush();

.....
```

My form in the twig template is like this:

```
{% if parts is defined %}
     <div class="inventorysearch">
       <form action="{{ path('updateparts', {'subid' : parts.subid}) }}" method="POST" >
            <input type="text" name="part" value="{{ parts.part }}" disabled><br />
            <input type="text" name="batch" value="{{ parts.batch }}" disabled><br />
            <input type="text" name="rack" required="required" value="{{ parts.rack }}"><br />
           <input type="text" name="acode" value="{{ parts.acode }}"><br />
           <input type="text" name="bcode" value="{{ parts.bcode }}"><br />
           <input type="integer" name="qty" required="required" value="{{ parts.qty }}"><br />
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Update</button>
       </form>
     </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best and recommended way is to use symfony's form builder

```
public function updatePartsAction(Request $request, $subid) {
    $r = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $r->getRepository('MainBundle:MainSub')->findOneById($subid);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Parts entity to edit.');
    }
    $form= $this->createFormBuilder($entity)
           ->add('part')
           ->add('batch')
           .... and so on the properties from your entity that you want them to edit
           ->getForm();
 if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == "POST") {
        $form->handleRequest($request)
        if ($form->isValid()) {
        $r->persist($form->getData());
        $r->flush();
        }
  }

}
```

In twig just render your `{{ form(form) }}`

The other way you ask for is not recommended and not a good practice but it depends on you how you are going to code your app the good way or bad way

```
public function updatePartsAction(Request $request, $subid) {
    $r = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $r->getRepository('MainBundle:MainSub')->findOneById($subid);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Parts entity to edit.');
    }
  if ($this->getRequest()->getMethod() == "POST") {
    $entity->setPath('get values from request')
     and others setters to which you want them to edit        
        $r->persist($entity);
        $r->flush();

  }
}
```

Comment: If we're going to talk about the "best & recommended" way, you should take it a step further and create a Form component that you pass the entity into. If you have a custom design you need to create a form view as well. createFormBuilder isn't ideal in typical situations. What if I want to have a page to add a new entity, or edit an existing one, or duplicate an existing entity but then be able to edit the properties of it. IMO if we're talking about the best way it should really be the best way is all :p

Comment: @skrilled i know there is a form type feature in symfony but if add this type of code i guess it will be far away for OP to digest it so i showed him directly using form builder for entity once OP is able to use at-least the form builder of symfony he can go further in future to create a form type also but i appreciate your point regarding  symfony's form type

Answer (score 0):

That concept goes against the entire purpose of MVC (trying to do it in the template/view), so I'm not sure what you meant by your last statement.

However, in your controller you should access the entity (model) via the entities methods.

I.e. if I have a $user entity with a username property, I should have a setUsername method and can do:

```
 $user->setUsername('theusername');
 $em->persist($user); 
 $em->flush();
```

Note that I used $em instead of your $r out of habit (it's what the documentation shows and what most programmers will use).

Also, using the form component is still a better method in the long haul.